# Will the free charge density on a disconnected capacitor plate change if I insert a dielectric?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance, polarization, dielectric

We have a **disconnected**  capacitor having charge density $\sigma_{1}$ on its positive plate.
Now we fill it with a dielectric as shown.
Will the **free charge density**(  the mobile charges on the capacitor plate not the bound charge of the dielectric)  change now? [image]

Answer (score 2):

The potential difference (and the resultant field) between the two conducting plates must be the same in both regions.  Because the induced charge on the surface of the dielectric tends to reduce the resultant field in that region, some free charge must move from the region without a dielectric to the region with the dielectric.

Comment: Thanks, could you be quantitative?

Comment: @YasirSadiq R.W. BIrd's answer is correct   I have posted an answer with quantitative details thats supports R.W. Bird's answer.

Comment: If you start with plates of area A and insert a dielectric with constant K and area $A_1$, then the charge redistributes: Q = ${σ_o}A = {σ_1}A_1 + {σ_2}A_2$  to match the condition ${ε_o}E = {σ_1}/K = σ_2$

Comment: @RW Bird, are you assuming that the field is downwards everywhere?(assuming top plate to be positive)

Comment: The resultant field is downward everywhere.

Comment: How can you say the field is downwards everywhere?

Comment: The induced charge on the surface of the dielectric will produce a field which points up, but it will always be smaller than the downward field produced by the charge on the plates.  The resultant must equal the field in the region with no dielectric in order for the potential difference between the plates to be the same in both regions.

Answer (score 1):

The charge on the capacitor plates will not change, however, the dielectric will develop a surface charge at its' two ends (the two parallel planes), which will be opposite in sign to the charge of the respective capacitor plates. This will lead to an increase in the capacitance. Also, the surface charge at the two ends of the dielectric must sum to zero.

Comment: Thanks, but i am interested in the free charge density, ie the mobile charge distribution on the capacitor plates .

Comment: If you post the actual question, maybe I can help you.

Comment: The capacitance is increased, not reduced.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the rest of the explanation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Will the free charge density( the mobile charges on the capacitor
> plate not the bound charge of the dielectric) change now?

The total charge on the capacitor is the same before and after inserting the dielectric (conservation of charge). However, when you inserted the dielectric you have, in effect, now two capacitors in parallel. One has air (or a vacuum) and the other filled with a dielectric. This will cause charge to migrate from the air capacitor to the capacitor with the dielectric, per the following explanation.

Since the capacitors are in parallel, the voltage has to be the same on the two capacitors. However the capacitances are now different because the presence of the dielectric reduces the effective electric field between the plates due to polarization of the dielectric. You can find a description of the effect of the dielectric on capacitance here: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/dielec.html which includes the derivation of the following equations:

For the capacitor without the dielectric its capacitance is

$$C=\frac{ε_{0}A}{d}$$

Where $ε_{0}$ = permittivity of air

For the capacitor with the dielectric its capacitance is

$$C=\frac{kε_{0}A}{d}$$

Where $kε_{0}$ = permittivity of the dielectric ($k$ a constant greater than 1)

So the capacitance of the capacitor with the dielectric is greater than the air capacitor.

Now, the relationship between capacitance, charge and voltage is

$$C=\frac{Q}{V}$$

Since the capacitor with the dielectric has the same voltage across the plates as the air capacitor, and since the capacitance of the capacitor with the dielectric is greater than the air capacitor, that means $Q$ must be greater for the capacitor with the dielectric. *Furthermore, since the total charge is unchanged, for this to occur charge must migrate from the air capacitor to the capacitor with the dielectric.*

Hope this helps.